# is it possible to pass value from radio button in form A to form B in php?

Tags: php

I have 2 forms right now. `Form A`, where I display the value inserted by user. (a user can insert as many value as they want). That's the reason why I put the radio button because at the end they need to choose only one to proceed. I have a button to save what a user has inserted.

`Form B`, where I have a button to go to another page that brings the value form the chosen radio button.

Comment: The better question is why you're trying to make use of two forms in the first place. Your radio button value will already be passed through in the submission of the first form.

Comment: If you POST the form, you get data in your `$_POST` variable at the destination form. This is pretty basic PHP, so I hope you've got a good reference book or [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) somewhere.

Comment: The short answer is "yes". The long answer is "why do you want to use PHP for something that should be done through Javascript and Ajax?"

Answer (score 0):

at `formA.html`

```
<form method="POST" action="formB.php">
<--your radio buttons goes here-->
<input type="submit" name="formAsubmit">
</form>
```

at `formB.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formAsubmit'])){
  //print user entered values on form A
    ?>
<form action="formB.php" method="POST">
<--your form B input fields goes here-->
<input type="submit" name="formBsubmit"/>
</form>
<php?
} elseif (isset($_POST['formBsubmit'])){
//Do what you want with formB informations
}
?>
```

Thats your dual forms

Comment: the forms are in the same php file

Comment: @Adam You want to brother with ajax and JS

Comment: Actually form A is where I fill the address (I have js alert for each of the input). User might want to use another address. That's why I put a radio button. For form B is where I display all the order summary and the total price and here is where I put the payment button. The reason I used two forms is because I have postage...the postage value will only exist after I fill the address form and save it.

Comment: @Adam, if you are that fond of BDSM, just modify Ramesh's solution to have both forms on 1 page and omit the 1st form's `action` attribute.